# Microservices API gateway vs. Microservices Chassis

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, microservices

I am new to microservices, I heard about microservices chassis but I cant find enough resources online. I would like to know what is the difference between microservices chassis framework and API gateway because as far as I know chassis frmework solves cross-cutting concern problems and some of them are already solved by API gateway .

is there any recommendations for a microservices chassis framework for .net ?

Comment: Hi nice question, nevertheless it's being marked as off-topic because of "asking for off-site resources" and "oppinion based". To overcome this you might want to rewrite your question and ask for common best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Cross cutting concerns**: In any enterprise application, there are a number of concerns which need to be taken care of in addition to the main business logic. ... Such concerns are logging, transaction handling, performance monitoring, security etc. These concerns are known as cross cutting concerns of the application.

To clarify this means that almost all micro-services has some common concerns. These concerns and how to manage them is Chassis. A microservice chassis is one such way to implement these cross-cutting concerns. Building a reusable chassis can help save time, enforce consistency across teams, and ensure that each service shares the same operational charateristics.

**API gateway** has other role in microservices. After each service registers itself in discovery service, API gateway has to use discovery service to make connection between clients and each service.

See this example:

[image: Micro service architecture]

The above example is from Spring implementation (Java).

Imagine situation when each service is in different port and address. Then the client must know all the addresses and ports of each service to be able to call them. And what happens if any of them change? Everything is just ruined.

To work around this problem, each service registers itself on a discovery server (in this example `Eureka`). API-Gateway then has to use that discovery service and create API addresses for each service. For example, it could forward any request in this pattern: `/{micro_service_name}/**` , to related registered service.
This means if `order-service` has `/orders/get/{order-id}` API, then clients must use `/order-service/orders/get/{order-id}` to access an order. API-gateway uses discovery server to redirect the request to matching service.

Comment: Nice complete answer, I still have a question though: are the actual end points passes to the client, so the client keeps track, or does the api gateway perform actual forwarding?

Comment: @Stefan Its usually a job for API gateway (as its name suggests)

Comment: So, to be clear: the gateway forwards the actual request and return the actual data to the client?

Comment: @Stefan Yes. Gateway forwards the request to proper micro-service and returns the data to user.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway in Microservices Architecture is mostly related to service discovery, that means in order to know which service to be called from which end-point one easy but insufficient way is to use API Gateway, simple a database of all services with their address and ports, compare this with containerization technology such as [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/) . Following are a set of articles that published about microservices in code-project, you can read and comment on your questions if you like.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-I
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-II
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-III